# how can i output current value of a variable in terraform during azure pipeline run?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

In powershell i usually use write-host to print out a variable whilst working in an azuredevops pipeline to check the value of a variable.

Can you do this in terraform? I am running some terraform code but want to check some of the terraform variable values during the pipeline run , is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#examples-1) :

```
- pwsh: |
    Write-Host "Non-secrets automatically mapped in, sauce is $env:SAUCE"
    Write-Host "Secrets are not automatically mapped in, secretSauce is $env:SECRETSAUCE"
    Write-Host "You can use macro replacement to get secrets, and they'll be masked in the log: $(secretSauce)"
    Write-Host "Future jobs can also see $env:SETVARS_OUTPUTSAUCE"
    write-Host "Future jobs can also see $(SetVars.outputSauce)"
```

Just run `terraform plan` part of the pipeline to check if the variables are set as expected.

You can also reference variables in `terraform output` if you need to.

Comment: im not sure re the above answer